# How to configure Strapi to show and external facing domain for URLs when being served behind a proxy?

Tags: nginx, strapi

I'm trying to have the links copied from an item in 'file upload' have the correct domain. Currently they use 'http://localhost:1337' which is incorrect because Strapi is running behind Nginx. Is there are way to specify what the external facing host is?

Answer (score 1):

Add the external facing domain info in the 'proxy' chunk of your `./config/environments/**/server.json` file.

```
{
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 1337,
  "proxy": {
    "enabled": true,
    "ssl": true,
    "host": "example.com",
    "port": 8443
  },
  "autoReload": {
    "enabled": true
  },
  "cron": {
    "enabled": true
  }
}
```

see https://strapi.io/documentation/3.x.x/configurations/configurations.html#server

Thanks to Carlos on the [Strapi slack channel](https://strapi.slack.io) for pointing me in the right direction!